# Find the duplicate in the object and add an increment value to it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I want to edit the label text so that whenever there are duplicates of the same label name, they are incremented so that they could be differentiated when displayed.

So the **input data** looks below:

```
const brandName = [
  {
    id: '1',
    label: 'Nike'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    label: 'Adidas'
  },
  {
    id: '3'
    label: 'Nike'
  }
]
```

And the **output data** of the function should display this:

```
const newBrandName = [
  {
    id: '1',
    label: 'Nike (1)'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    label: 'Adidas'
  },
  {
    id: '3'
    label: 'Nike (2)'
  }
]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
function findDuplicates(brandName){
  var l = 0
  var r = tournaments.length - 1
  var count = 1
  while(r < tournaments.length){
    if(tournaments[l].label === tournaments[r].label){
      tournaments[l].label += count
      count += 1
      tournaments[r].label += count
    }
    r -= 1
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could use a JavaScript inbuilt array function?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @0stone0 Hey stone, I'm trying to re-edit this code right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274087/add-an-incrementing-number-to-end-of-string-in-javascript-so-there-are-no-duplic

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Use the [edit] button to add some code to the question.

Comment: @0stone0 Added my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your attempt comes up with `tournaments`, but here is my attempt;

---

First, we [group the brands by label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects), then we know which one are found multiple times.

Then using `reduce()` we can flatten the multidimensional back to the array you started with, but add the (index + 1) for those where the array has more then 1 object in it

**Note**: The order  of object in the array won't be the after this!

```js
const brandName = [
  {
    id: '1',
    label: 'Nike'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    label: 'Adidas'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    label: 'Nike'
  }
];

const grouped = brandName.reduce((c, p) => {
    (c[p.label] ||= []).push(p);
    return c;
}, {});

const wrapped = Object.values(grouped).reduce((c, i) => {
  if (i.length > 1) {
      i = i.map((a, i) => {
          a.label = `${a.label} (${i + 1})`;
          return a;
      })
  }
  return [ ...c, ...i ];
}, []);

console.log(wrapped);
```

The above logs:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "label": "Nike (1)"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "label": "Nike (2)"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "label": "Adidas"
  }
]
```

Comment: Brilliant solution @0stone0, it works flawlessly. Although I'm getting an error message from TypeScript saying "Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)" and "Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488). " Do you have any quick solution to that?